# Adding a custom action to Devise Registrations..Unknown Action Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After Googling everywhere about how I can fix this I decided to post a question. I'm trying to add a custom action "create_pro" to the Devise Registrations controller so I can create a user with additional fields (A pro user). This form is on the same page as the devise create action for a user.

I keep getting the following error after submitting the form:

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'create_pro' could not be found for
>   Devise::RegistrationsController

*How can I fix this?*

**Routes**

```
  devise_for :users,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  devise_scope :user do
    post "gopro", :to => "devise/registrations#create_pro"
  end
```

**Registrations Controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :token

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome to Banking Analytics."
      redirect_to '/mybank'
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def create_pro
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome to Banking Analytics."
      redirect_to '/mybank'
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<div class="signup_form_basic">
<%= simple_form_for @user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'registrations', :action => 'create_pro') do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :label => 'Username ( Your Email )', :placeholder => 'Email Address' %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :label => 'Password', :placeholder => 'Password' %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :label => 'Confirm Password', :placeholder => 'Password Confirmation' %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign Up  >>", class: 'btn btn-inverse' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer for the 'Unknown Action error' that you are facing, but I think the current solution is sub-optimal.

Since your goal is to have the following two classes of users

1. Pro-users, and
2. Regular (Non-pro) users,

it is probably best to follow the suggestion at [How To: Customize routes to user registration pages](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-routes-to-user-registration-pages) and set up parallel structures for the two types of users.

That would be much more in line with the relationship between the two types of users.